TransportError: HTTPSConnectionPool
import gspread
from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials
import pandas as pd

scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
         "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]

creds = Credentials.from_service_account_file('C:/Users/Prince.Afful-Quansah/Downloads/gsheets-workspace-123-0c8a1f809edf.json', scopes=scope)

client = gspread.authorize(creds)

sheet = client.open_by_url('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UnGukBaBIdu3dt66RFhvWKZnwRszAKRtIHcqMOzcQ88/edit#gid=0').sheet1

existing_data = pd.DataFrame(sheet.get_all_records())

new_data = Bulk_SMS_New_filtered

updated_data = existing_data.append(new_data, ignore_index=True)

data = updated_data.values.tolist()

headers = updated_data.columns.tolist()
data.insert(0, headers)

sheet.update('A1', data)

I wanted to add the results from a table I created on python and store the results in google sheets. I have already worked on connecting the python to the Google Cloud Console.
The results of the code comes with:
TransportError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='oauth2.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /token (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)')))

